# python - selenium script syntax error

Tags: python, selenium, syntax

Okay, I used selenium to test some automation, which I got to work. I did an export of the script for python. When I tried to run the python script it generated, it gave me a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error message. Here's the python script in question:

```
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class WakeupCall(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://the.web.site")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_wakeup_call(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/index.php#deposit")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        sel.click("link=History")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        try: self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("key phrase number 1."))
        except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
```

The last line is what generated the "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error message. A "^" was under the comma. The rest of the script goes as follows:

```
    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the problem? Is there a syntax error? If there is, could you please post the stack dump?

Comment: What version of python are you using? Your code works fine for me on 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Python have changed the exception handler syntax.

```
except AssertionError as e:
```

Comment: Here's the command execution and what follows: `python3 WakeupCall.py
  File "WakeupCall.py", line 23
    except AssertionError, e: self.verificationErrors.append(str(e))
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` Python version is 3.1.2

Comment: If this is not everything that was requested in order to give the necessary information to get the help I need, please let me know what I need to do. I'm a relative newbie.